# when <use>ing a filtered shape - filter disappears in Chrome

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to create a "mirror" effect of a shape that has a filter applied to it in SVG. Pretty simple mirroring - just give it some distance from the original shape and flip it. The original shape has a "glow" filter applied to it.

When rendering this in different browsers:

- Edge (non-Chromium) renders exactly as expected.
- Chrome doesn't render the mirrored shape with the filter applied - just the original pathed shape.
- Firefox doesn't even render the filter. Ugh.

[image: mirroring filtered shape results in Edge, Chrome and Firefox]

So, given that Edge will be moving to Chromium soon, I'd like to keep this affect of the mirrored shape having the filter applied. Here's what I'm doing - can I do anything different to have the Edge result in Chrome?

```html
<svg name="glow only" x="100" y="50" overflow="visible" fill="green" stroke="orange" stroke-width="3.25">
    <defs>
        <filter id="glow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 100 0" result="glowColor" />
            <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="5.5" in="glowColor" result="thickenify" />
            <feGaussianBlur in="thickenify" stdDeviation="2.5" result="glowIt" />
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="glowIt" />
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <use id="mirroredContent" xlink:href="#contentForMirroringWithFilter" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,4.89842541528951E-16,155.25)" />
    <g id="contentForMirroringWithFilter">
        <path d="M0,0L60,0L72,12L72,72L0,72Z" filter="url(#glow)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this in Chrome?

---

**EDIT 1**: This is starting to look like an issue with flipping. If I use other transforms, like:
`<use xlink:href="#contentForMirroringWithFilter" transform="rotate(50)"/>` and
 `<use xlink:href="#contentForMirroringWithFilter" transform="translate(0, 80)"/>`, the filter is preserved. Even when I apply a `scale` that is positive, it works, like 
`<use xlink:href="#contentForMirroringWithFilter" transform="translate(0, 80) scale(1,1.2)"/>`.

However, as soon as I apply a negative scale for flipping, that's when it flips out and doesn't display the filter: 
`<use xlink:href="#contentForMirroringWithFilter" transform="translate(0, 152) scale(1,-1)  "/>`.

Is this a bug, or is there a different way I should be trying the flip?

**EDIT 2**:

- A bug has been filed for Firefox at bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1577566.
- The bug identified by Kaiido in Chrome has been amended with this issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=595244
- I'm still looking at a workaround that would allow me to applied the filter and subsequently work with the `<use/>'d` shaped (with filter applied), such as setting different transformations, opacity, etc.

Comment: Firefox displays as Edge for me although I'm on a Mac here. Do you have webrender enabled? You could try disabling it via setting gfx.webrender.force-disabled in about:config if you do. At any rate if you have a Firefox bug it's best discussed/tracked in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG)

Comment: For Chrome that's a known bug with feMorphology: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=595244 Here is an [MCVE](https://jsfiddle.net/kmwdju4e/)

Comment: @RobertLongson, thanks for the reply. I tried disabling it as you directed, it had no effect. I'm on v.68.0.2 (64-bit) Windows 10.

Comment: @Kaiido. Thanks for this link. That's looking like the issue. But it's been open for 3 years. I've never dealt with actual bugs in Chrome before - is there a likelihood it will ever get resolved? Can I do anything, like file a new bug? Just not sure what my options are here to try to get it fixed.

Comment: The recommended way is to "star" the issue. A less recommended way, but still often seen is a friendly reminder on the issue itself that it's still affecting active website (yours). Now, in your position I wouldn't expect any fix soon,  so I think I would just star it and go ahead with the workaround that you have received.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I've filed on at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1577566.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution would be putting both the path and the mirrored inside the same g element and apply the filter to the `<g>`like so:

```html
<svg name="glow only" x="100" y="50" overflow="visible" fill="green" stroke="orange" stroke-width="3.25">
    <defs>
        <filter id="glow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 100 0" result="glowColor" />
            <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="5.5" in="glowColor" result="thickenify" />
            <feGaussianBlur in="thickenify" stdDeviation="2.5" result="glowIt" />
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="glowIt" />
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
    </defs>
  <g filter="url(#glow)">
    <use id="mirroredContent" xlink:href="#contentForMirroringWithFilter" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,4.89842541528951E-16,155.25)" />
    <g id="contentForMirroringWithFilter">
        <path d="M0,0L60,0L72,12L72,72L0,72Z"  />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response. Unfortunately, I have situation where I'll need to further modify the filter that shouldn't apply to original shape, such as size, offset of the mirrored object. If there's a workaround through other means, I'd love to hear about it. I tried adding another `<use/>` with an `feImage` filter and then flipping/scaling that one, but it didn't work. So I'm coming up empty on ideas. :(